# ansible match list element

Tags: ansible, jinja2

```
---
- name: main
  hosts: localhost
  become: true
  vars:
    allowed_options: [AllowAgent,RSAAuthentication,RSATokeN]
    match_config:
          test:
            matchkey: 'User'
            matchvalue: 'user1'
            allowagent: 'domaintoken'
            rsatoken: 'XXXXXZZZ0000000'
          test2:
            matchkey: 'Address'
            matchvalue: '162.243.72.0/24,192.43.120.0/23'
            rsaauthentication: 'enabled'
            invalidkey: invalidvalue
  tasks:
   - name: deploy
     template:
        src: xa.j2
        dest: /tmp/xa.txt
```

### template file

```
{% if (allowed_options is defined) and allowed_options %}
{% for k,v in match_config.items() %}
Match {{ v.matchkey }} {{ v.matchvalue }}
{% for optname, optval in v.items() if optname not in ['matchkey', 'matchvalue'] %}
{% if optname in allowed_options|lower %}
  {{ optname }} {{ optval }}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

I get the right output:

```
Match User user1
  allowagent domaintoken
  rsatoken XXXXXZZZ0000000
Match Address 162.243.72.0/24,192.43.120.0/23
  rsaauthentication enabled
```

But, I would prefer

```
Match User user1
  AllowAgent domaintoken
  RSATokeN XXXXXZZZ0000000
Match Address 162.243.72.0/24,192.43.120.0/23
  RSAAuthentication enabled
```

I just plain and simple can't figure out...

So I just compare case insensitive in jinja2 template and if it match  just to use list[element]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the below dictionary

```yaml
  allowed_dict: "{{ dict(allowed_options|map('lower')|zip(allowed_options)) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  allowed_dict:
    allowagent: AllowAgent
    rsaauthentication: RSAAuthentication
    rsatoken: RSATokeN
```

and  use it in the template

```yaml
{% for k,v in match_config.items() %}
Match {{ v.matchkey }} {{ v.matchvalue }}
{% for optname, optval in v.items() %}
{% if optname in allowed_dict %}
  {{ allowed_dict[optname] }} {{ optval }}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

gives

```ini
Match User user1
  AllowAgent domaintoken
  RSATokeN XXXXXZZZ0000000
Match Address 162.243.72.0/24,192.43.120.0/23
  RSAAuthentication enabled
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    allowed_options: [AllowAgent, RSAAuthentication, RSATokeN]
    allowed_dict: "{{ dict(allowed_options|map('lower')|zip(allowed_options)) }}"
    match_config:
          test:
            matchkey: 'User'
            matchvalue: 'user1'
            allowagent: 'domaintoken'
            rsatoken: 'XXXXXZZZ0000000'
          test2:
            matchkey: 'Address'
            matchvalue: '162.243.72.0/24,192.43.120.0/23'
            rsaauthentication: 'enabled'
            invalidkey: invalidvalue

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: allowed_dict

    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for k,v in match_config.items() %}
          Match {{ v.matchkey }} {{ v.matchvalue }}
          {% for optname, optval in v.items() %}
          {% if optname in allowed_dict %}
            {{ allowed_dict[optname] }} {{ optval }}
          {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}
```

If the variable *allowed_options* might be undefined set it to an empty list

```yaml
  allowed_dict: "{{ dict(allowed_options|d([])|map('lower')|
                         zip(allowed_options|d([]))) }}"
```

This would result in an empty dictionary

```yaml
  allowed_dict: {}
```

---

Q: Explain the construct zip(allowed_options)

A: Take a look at the intermediate results

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          allowed_options|map('lower'):
          {{ allowed_options|map('lower')|to_yaml }}
          allowed_options|map('lower')|zip(allowed_options):
          {{ allowed_options|map('lower')|zip(allowed_options)|to_yaml }}
          dict(allowed_options|map('lower')|zip(allowed_options)):
          {{ dict(allowed_options|map('lower')|zip(allowed_options))|to_nice_yaml }}
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: |-
    allowed_options|map('lower'):
    [allowagent, rsaauthentication, rsatoken]
  
    allowed_options|map('lower')|zip(allowed_options):
    - [allowagent, AllowAgent]
    - [rsaauthentication, RSAAuthentication]
    - [rsatoken, RSATokeN]
  
    dict(allowed_options|map('lower')|zip(allowed_options)):
    allowagent: AllowAgent
    rsaauthentication: RSAAuthentication
    rsatoken: RSATokeN
```

Comment: sooper, please, can explain this construct ? **zip(allowed_options)** ?

Comment: I added an example.